# Get attachment names from Tika

Tags: apache-tika

I'm parsing an EML file (RFC822) using Tika, but for some reason I cannot get the attachment names. I get the body, to, cc, bcc, attachments text, etc but not the attachments names. Any ideas? Below is the code I'm using.

```
var handler = new BodyContentHandler();
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\testemail.eml"));
            ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
            var parser = new RFC822Parser();

            parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);
            Debug.WriteLine("Contents of the document:" + handler.toString());
            Debug.WriteLine("Metadata of the document:");
            String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

            foreach (String name in metadataNames)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
            }
```

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? The Server? The command line app? Tika facade? Tika parser jars? Other?

Comment: I'm calling it from a .net program. I'm using the .net wrapper around Tika. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Which wrapper? What code are you using? The way to get the information varies wildly with how you call Tika

Comment: Just added the code I'm using. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you try the approaches [outlined on the Tika wiki for handling Recursion, Attachments, Embedding and metadata](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/RecursiveMetadata)?

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. It retrieves the names from .MSG but not from .EML

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the most recent version of Tika?

Comment: I'm using the wrapper for .net. I don't know what version they are using. I'll try to do it in Java and I'll let you know how that one go.